# Force portrait image in cordova/phonegap

Tags: cordova, photo, portrait

Id like to force all pictures taken in my cordova app to be portrait. This goes for both android and iphone.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant do it. you can force orientation of application but not picture

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: But you can rotate a picture, if you want.

Comment: @reporter if you ask someone if you're attractive and he/she says 'no', you don't consider that as an answer also, right? stackoverflow mods logic ftw.

Comment: @OP why would you want to rotate horizontal image just to make it portrait? doesnt seem proper.

Comment: The most common way to take a picture in my app is portrait. But users accidentally twist their phone causing landscape (some androids seems sensitive). So to fix it I need a button where the user can rotate the pic.

Comment: Or if your photo app is being used to capture things like printed documents which always have a vertical layout.