# Orientation of Phonegap camera picture (Android)

Tags: android, cordova, camera

I've been searching for a while, but haven't found a solution.

I'm trying to get my app to capture a photo but always force the photo to be a portrait photo, regardless if you take the photo with your phone in portrait or landscape (Pretty much how Snapchat handles photos being taken).

I've made the app only portrait and that works fine, but if I take a photo with my phone in landscape, the android camera then flips the photo 90 degrees to be landscape.

As it's a portrait only app, I want to be able to show the full image in portrait (the user can turn their phone if the image is sideways!)

Any thoughts on this? I've tried setting targetWidth, targetHeight & correctOrientation but cannot seem to get it to work at all.

Here's what currently happens:
http://postimg.org/image/9k51ptfb1/

And here's what I want to happen:
http://postimg.org/image/mkxvu7nlj/

Note - the suggested duplication has an answer of "can't be done" with no other details, which is obviously not an answer!

Thanks,

Gary

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25480022/force-portrait-image-in-cordova-phonegap

Comment: That one has accepted an answer of "no, can't do it" - Surely there's got to be a way to do it, even if it means modifying the camera plug in? (Snapchat do it after all!)